# How to fetch/copy files from a TFS (Team Foundation Server) with C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, tfs

I am required to do an escrow of some folders and files located within an TFS. I can move this between my local folders but I still don't have a clue on how to do fetch files from the server. have any of you guys made this before?

Comment: What's your real requirements? get the latest version of files from TFS server?

Answer (score 1):

If this file is under TFS version control (TFVC)There is a TFS REST API to get the file content: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/items#getafile
There is also corresponding Git API, if your file is in TFS Git version control:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/items#streamafile
Finally, there is a good article that shows how to call REST API from a C# application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: You should mention the [Client Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as the OP has not specified the TFS version, and older ones have no REST API